# Query Google sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheet that I would like to query and match people their job and dates of availability to make a planning. I will be dealing with 30000 lines of data and I would appreciate any solution.

I have tried using many methods for several hours with no luck and I am hoping that someone will have the answer to my problem.

Here is the sheet with sample data and the results that I want to achieve:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1crWbpIpnDUr8OY5TvIZv8Bl3gebZyYRFlAmxcqy362E/edit?usp=sharing

You will notice that I already use a query to get data from Planning sheet to use filters. 
The problem for me is I need to list and match a teacher and and an assistant with the same date with at least one of them has a car.

The sheet in question is called FILTERS and I need to list on the right side of the sheet the names (column A) the job (column C) their car (column D) and the DATE (column G)

There are 3 possibilities to have the data in a usable way and I have given examples of desired results on the right of FILTERS sheet.

I am not sure whether I need an array formula or a script and I have no idea how to write a script.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I hit a brick wall and don't know what to do.

Comment: you may rebuild the question. To clerify your needs try explaining this `I need to list and match a teacher and and an assistant with the same date and at least one of them has a car.` What sheet / column is needed to be matched? Where is the date? Where is the info obout a car? I think you need an `arrayformula` for that.

Answer (score 0):

First let's fix syntax error and data range:

> =query(A8:K; "select  A, Sum(J) GROUP BY A pivot G ORDER BY A desc  ",1)

probably must be:

> =query(A8:J; "select  A, Sum(J) GROUP BY A pivot G ORDER BY A desc  ";1)

Then get in the test cell:

```
This what tried :       
NAME    null    2017-8-25
NAME 1      1
```

But You already have formula in A8:

> =Query(PLANNING!A1:O; "select A, B, M, O, E, N, C, F, G, sum(H) where A starts with """&B3&""" and M contains """&B4&""" and E contains
>   """&B5&""" and N contains """&B6&""" and F contains """&B2&""" and I
>   starts with """&D2&""" and J starts with """&D3&""" and K starts with
>   """&D4&""" and L starts with """&D5&"""GROUP BY C, E, M, N, O, F, G,
>   A, B ORDER BY  C, M, E" ;1)

just need to add `TEACHER` in B4 (Code validation)